# Alfa AWUS036NHR connection issues

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, and the wifi card, Broadcom BCM4313, running driver wl0, shows networks but won't connect to them. I've kind of given up trying to fix this, and bought an external wifi adapter, an Alfa AWUS036NHR, which uses the driver rtl8192cu. This works ok, but every few minutes, the connection freezes. Sometimes it is fixed by disconnecting and re-connecting to the AP, but sometimes i have to un-plug it and plug it in again. I can also re-set it by removing and re-loading the driver with modprobe, but I'd like to know if there's a definitive solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Btw. I am using a Lenovo G580

Comment: What have you tried for the Broadcom? Have you removed brcmwl-kernel-source and installed linux-firmware-nonfree?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having crazy problems with lenovo G480 and the broadcom adapter. What I've found to work most is to install this [compat-wireless 3.5](http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1.tar.bz2)
download it, decompress it(possible with the ubuntu archive manager), then go into the folder you decompressed:

- $ make
- $ sudo make install

Restart your laptop...It has worked for me better than anyting ive managed to find online in the last week!
If you still cant connect, try changing the settings of your router to:
WPA 2/WPA Personal AES, 802.11 b or g (do not put it on n or b/g/n).
I would also recommend you to try a change the channel (there might be a lot of wifi networks around you that are disturbing your wifi reception)

  Good luck!